# How does the C# Item property work?

Tags: c#

I've been learning C# coming from a Java and C++ background. Some classes have an `Item` property that appears to be like C++'s `operator[]` and Java's very normal `get` and `set` methods.

However, I can't find any mention on how this property works. C++'s operator overloading approach simply gives you the index and expects the appropriate value. Java's approach doesn't even require language support.

So how does this magical property work? The syntax that most of the MDN pages give isn't very clear. Eg, here's from the list page:

```
public T this[
    int index
] { get; set; }
```

While it's clear why there's a mention of `get` and `set` (eg, there's a read only list that only lets you get and not set items), it's not clear what this syntax is saying as a whole.

Comment: It is an [Indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx%28v=vs.140%29.aspx).

Comment: this is an indexer property, refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288464%28v=vs.71%29.aspx for more information

Comment: @Sayse, No, I'm referring to the `Item` property of collections like `List<T>` that can be used with syntax like `list[123]` and `list[123] = newValue`. The Java equivalent is a very transparent `list.get(123)` and `list.set(123, newValue)`, but it's less clear how the C# way works.

Comment: @Sayse: It is not an auto-implemented property.  The implementation is not shown in documentation.

Comment: @BenVoigt - I appear to have misread the question

Comment: Don't learn from decompiled code before you get more experience with the language and environment. `Item` is *not* used in C# - it's only used in IL. In C#, it's simply an indexer property. You're reading the wrong docs - instead of looking at an actual class using an indexer, read about indexers - e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx

Comment: Or link to newer version of the article linked by @Alex - [Indexers (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx)

Comment: @Luaan, I was reading documentation and confused when I couldn't find any mention of how to get/set items in collections (usually using an overridden `[]` or `get`/`set` methods). The documentation doesn't make it immediately clear that this `Item` property is really an overridden `[]`. It seems that the source code is much more readable than the documentation.

Comment: It fact, yes it is like C++ `operator[]()` overloading, but like other C# properties, you can write separate code for get and set (to allow reassignment in C++, you'd return a reference or a proxy object)

Comment: Additionally, you can index by more than just an integer index. This is what is done e.g. in a generic `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`: `public TValue this[TKey key] { get; set; }`

Comment: Yeah, that's my point - the tricky part is that CIL, the intermediate language ("bytecode") of .NET, has many differences from C#. So sometimes you'll see stuff like `get_Name`, even though that's actually a getter from a property `Name`, or `Item`, which is actually an indexer. Those are just conventions when translating e.g. C# to IL. The code you've shown in your question is the *signature* of the indexer (e.g. it returns an element of type `T` and takes an argument of type `int`, which is the index), not the implementation.